# Nested Functions Javascript Word Count

Tags: javascript, function, count, nested, cpu-word

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of words, characters, spaces of a word. I have the following code so far:

```
function superCounter(str) { 
var chars = str.split("").length; 
var words = str.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length; 
var spaces = str.split(" ").length - 1; 
};
```

It is returning undefined. I know this function has 3 other functions inside of it. How can I get one function to return the 3 other nested functions? I think I am not writing this function properly :(

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return your final values from the function in an object (since you have more than one value to return):

```js
    function superCounter(str) { 
        var chars = str.length; 
        var words = str.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length; 
        var spaces = str.split(" ").length - 1; 
        return {spaces: spaces, words: words, chars: chars};
    };  

    var result = superCounter("The quick brown fox jumped over the fence");
    document.write(result.chars + "<br>");
    document.write(result.words + "<br>");
    document.write(result.spaces + "<br>");
```